# Running a task in the background

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a requirement where I need to run a stored procedure and send the results as emails at regular intervals of time . The interval of time is set by the user & the user can also set to start of stop the alerts.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTimeInterval" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="15MIN" Value="15"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="30MIN" Value="30"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="1Hr" Value="60"></asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem Text="2Hrs" Value="120"></asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbSetAlertsOn" GroupName="Group1" Text="Set Alerts On" Value="Yes"
                        AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Group1_CheckedChanged" />
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rbSetAlertsOff" GroupName="Group1" Text="Set Alerts Off" Value="No"
                        AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Group1_CheckedChanged" />
```

Now, Everything is good as long as the user is on the aspx page. I want the alert emails to show even when the user navigates to another page . That is , once the settings are set, I would like the user to receive the emails or not irrespective of whether he is on the website or is logged off . Also the next time he logs into the website, I would like him to see exactly the same settings that he had used before logging off.

Is there a way I can do it ?

Comment: Perhaps you want to set up a service?  Have the aspx page send the initial requirements to the service, and the service sends the email.  Long running processes or timed processes like this dont work well over a web page.

Comment: Ideally you'd have an entirely separate process handling this work that's not running within the context of ASP.  Have another process/service running on that machine and have your ASP code send a request to that service for it to go do work.

Comment: Check out http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you a service, windows service, that will do the sending email job after required from the user, and about the user preference, you can set a cookie or save in DB.

Comment: Seconded on the Windows Service.

Answer (score 0):

You can also achieve this with Azure service bus with a worker process and/or the scheduler in Azure mobile services.